How can I write proofs formally and accurately?
Once I was learning elementary linear algebra, my teacher said I should use double arrow($\implies$) in formal proof but I should use single arrow($\rightarrow$) to represent how a matrix is changed during a sequence of EROs, because double arrow is an mathematical sign which means 'implies' while single arrow is just a symbol.
However, in a logic textbook, the author said "In this textbook, single arrow is the formal sign we've defined before while double arrow isn't. If you're more interested, search for 'metalanguage'.". Also there was no implies sign at the textbook while author just placed lots of statements in a column and writing a conclusion below a long bar to state proof.
For me, the usage of double arrow which my teacher said sounds weird. There are two reasons. [1] First, if we use the implies sign repeatedly, there is ambiguity. Even more, the real meaning of the sentence is neither of two interpretation. [2] Second, sometimes we should deal with sentences about the logical relationship between statements, like proving fundamental theorem of linear algebra. In this situations, it will be confusing to use double arrows both inside of the statement and to represent the relationship of sentences.
For example, if I intend to 'we know p and we can derive q from p, and we also can derive r from q', I might write [p $\implies$ q $\implies$ r] in the proof to follow teacher's instruction. However, two statements "p implies (q implies r)" and "(p implies q) implies r" are not the same, and neither of them really means "r is true whenever p is true".
Rather then, I think it'll be more accurate to write two statements respectively and using English, like ["p AND p $\rightarrow$ q $\implies$' q". Also, "q $\rightarrow$ r" so we can get r]. But writing like this would take a long time and wouldn't be used broadly.
So my question is, (1) what is mathematically recommended way to write the proof? (2) isn't it wrong to use double arrow to describe relationships between sentences like the example written above?
Edit: Thanks to helpful comments, I could expand my understanding about $\rightarrow$ and $\implies$. Meanwhile, I am curious about what should I use instead of the arrows.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Symbols are a tool for communication, and different people use different conventions. Mathematical writing should always include enough explanation (in complete, natural-language sentences) to make it clear what the symbols mean and how they're being used. (Depending on the audience, it might be clear from context.)

By convention, $A \to B \to C$ always means $A \to (B \to C)$; just like $a - b - c$ always means $(a - b) - c$.

Exactly. "in a logic textbook, the author said "In this textbook,..." " (highlighted by me).

@NaïmFavier As many have pointed our already, different books, different conventions.  And so it is with something like $p \to q \to r$. Yes, some books are ok with such an expression, and use a convention that parses it as $p \to (q \to r)$. But other books assume no such convention and consider $p \to q \to r$ to be ungrammatical. Also, neither interpretation is equivalent to $(p \to q) \land (q \to r)$, which was really the main point of the OP in that passage.

The use of the symbols $\implies$ and $\to$ can vary from book to book. Two different books can use a different symbol for the same concept, and two different books can use the same symbol for different concepts. So yeah, I can understand how this is all pretty confusing, because there is some ambiguity involved. The important thing is to always get clear on how a specific book uses a symbol.
In fact, even the expression 'formal proof' is ambiguous.  In logic, this has a pretty clear definition: it is a demonstration that manipulates expressions in the language of formal logic, and where those manipulations have to follow very specific formal patterns.  In mathematics, we are typically far less strict about the notation: you can use English phrases like 'Therefore', 'We now see that', etc. as part of the mathematical proof. Even individual statements can be phrased in English rather than some specific logical or mathematical language. Typically the thing that instructors/book require is merely that the proof follows a very clear organization and structure: something that very clearly lays out assumptions, and where you clearly indicate what follows from what: it is a 'formal' proof in that sense.
Indeed, to clearly indicate what follows from what, in math proofs we often use expressions like $1 \implies 2$ to indicate that 2 follows from 1 given the mathematical domain you are currently working with. This is closely aligned to the meta-logical usage of the symbol $\implies$, which denotes that some formal logic expression logically follows from some other formal logic expression. Indeed, we could try to formalize the domain with a bunch of axioms, and express those using a set $\Gamma$ of formal logic expressions, and if we also capture 1 and 2 using formal logic expressions $\phi$ and $\psi$ respectively, we can then make the purely meta-logical claim that $\Gamma, \phi \implies \psi$
Anyway, in both math and logic, the $\implies$ denotes a kind of reasoning that you do. It says: if you have [this], then you can (mathematically/logically) infer [that].
Also, in both math and logic, you can write things like $p \implies q \implies r$ as a shorthand way to say two things: $p \implies q$ and $q \implies r$.
When you were in your linear algebra class, you were definitely doing mathematical proofs, and I highly doubt you did formal proofs in the much stricter formal logic tradition. So for those proofs, the use of $\implies$ was probably completely appropriate. Also, it seems like the use of $\to$ in that particular context was apparently used to express some kind of mathematical operation on matrices. So that was indeed not at all used as a symbol of inference or reasoning, as you teacher indicated. Indeed, the $\to$ as used in the context of that linear algebra course is not at all like the $\to$ symbol you are finding in the logic textbook you are now working with: a good example of two different books using the same symbol for different concepts.
In the context of formal logic, the $\to$ is a truth-functional operator, also called the material implication. In this context, the expression $p \to q$ merely expresses a claim that would be considered false if $p$ is true, and $q$ is false, but true otherwise. This is a much weaker claim than saying that $q$ mathematically or logically follows from $p$.
Indeed, your $p \to q \to r$ is a case in point.  As you point out, as a formal logic statement it is ambiguous: is it  $(p \to q) \to r$ or $p \to (q \to r)$?  And even if your text has a rule for parsing such statements a certain way (as Naim says in the Comments, some books will see $p \to q \to r$ as $p \to (q \to r)$, although many books do not have such a parsing convention and consider it simply to be an ungtrammatical expression), please note that neither $(p \to q) \to r$ nor $p \to (q \to r)$ is equivalent to $(p \to q) \land (q \to r)$. So no, this is completely unlike anything like the $\implies$.
OK, so what are you to use now with the logic textbook you are currently using?  Well, as you found, your logic textbook depicts a proof as a long column of logic statements, the inferences are indicated by the use of a line number system: if line 6 refers to lines 3 and 5, then that is the formal proofs way of indicating that line 6 logically follows from lines 3 and 5. We could denote this as $3,5 \implies6$, but there is no further need for that. Indeed, from the quote in the second paragraph in your question, it looks like your logic textbook isn't going to make meta-logical claims using meta-logical symbols like $\implies$, which means that indeed, you should not be using that symbol, and just stick to $\to$ in the context of that book.

If OP sticks to $\longrightarrow$ to denote an implication, what is OP going to use for elementary row operations? There is nothing wrong with OP's teacher's advice but your answer just confuses  OP imho more.

@KurtG. Have you misread this answer?

@KurtG. I thought I was pretty clear in my answer: I encourage the use of $\implies$ for something like mathematical/logical implication, and reserve $\to$ for the truth-functional operator (the 'row operations' as you call it). I most definitely do not encourage the use of $\to$ to denote such an implication, and I am confused how you could even read that in my answer. But in the end the OP should use symbols consistently with how the particular book/instructor wants them to be used.

I find your last sentence quite confusing. "Indeed, your book apparently isn't going to make meta-logical claims using meta-logical symbols like $\implies$," [how do we know which book exactly OP was using?]. "which means that indeed, you should not be using that symbol" [you mean $\Rightarrow$?] , "and just stick to $\to$" [instead of $\Rightarrow$?]. Finally I fail to see what the logical use of $\to$ has to do with elementary row operations of matrices in linear algebra.

@KurtG.  OK, thanks for explaining!  And sorry, I was confused about what you meant by row operations .. I thought maybe you were referring to how we analyze truth-functional operators in a truth-table, but now I see you were talking about the OP's linear algebra course :P  And no, I don't know the book the OP is using, but the quote in the second paragraph strongly suggests it is not using the $\implies$ symbol as it is not doing metalanguage.

Thank you for a kind and detailed answer! I'm worried I'm appreiciating so late. Thanks to your explanation, now I know that $\implies$ can be used like < just like a<b<c mean a<b and b<c, and I should be so stick to 'formal proof' so much. Also the intention of teacher was to differ the sign representing ERO and logical implies. Lastly, the best part was why we're using $\implies$ in proofs and how to write it formally! Thank you so much.

@lIlIllII l You're welcome!  You can accept the Answer by selecting the check symbol to the left of my Answer.

The use of symbols is just a convention. Some are widely spread and shared, others can vary depending on the country. For example the set of natural integers ($\Bbb N$) always contains $0$ in France, while in USA, it is common to use $0\notin\Bbb N$. For conventions like that, the best way is to start a mathematical text by explicitly describing which conventions are used throughout it.
The usage of $\implies$ for an implication is widely spread, and the name of the symbol in LaTeX is indeed \implies. That being said any author can explicitely define a different convention for a book or a paper without any problem provided they consistently stick to that convention. You just should avoid using non-standard conventions in short texts like mathSE posts.
